# add style to h1 tag without editing

Tags: css

Im new to html/css and was wondering if someone had advice on a current problem I have.

For a site I am working I have the header under the h1 css tag. I want to add padding to it, but I don't want to affect all the other headers on other pages with the same h1 tag.  What is  the best way to add padding to the h1 in css without affecting all the other headers using the same tag.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question ^^ and I apologize for such an simple question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you will likely need to give that head a class name.
If you only want the styles reflected on the homepage for instance, you should assign a class name:

```
h1.main {
  padding:5px;
}
```

All other headers would use the default  styles.
In your HTML, you would simply add the class:

```
<h1 class="main">Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1

You can define inline styles

```
<h1 style="padding-bottom: 10px">Header</h1>
```

## Method 2

You could create a class

```
<h1 class="specialHeader">Header</h1>
```

Then your CSS would look something like

```
h1.specialHeader {
    padding-bottom: 10px;    
}
```

## Method 3

Access it by some parent div which is unique to this page. Your CSS would be

```
#mainPage h1{
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
```

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73Gxu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
header h1{ /*Some sort of more specific selector*/
  padding: /*Value*/;
}
```

Insert this into your CSS file, and this should work for you

This will only effect `h1` that is in the `header`. 
So your HTML would be:

```
<header>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</header>
```

Link: [jsfiddle to check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/BRhe2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (or id) to your specific h1 element; for example:

HTML

```
<h1 class="header">blabla</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1.header {
    padding: 2em;
}
```

Although for headers, you should use the HTML5 `<header>` element.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you want the first H1 tag on the page. If you give the surrounding HTML, I could give a better selector, but this will style the first instance of an H1 tag on the page.

```
h1:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: You should add more alternatives, because this most likely isn't what he wants.

Comment: As of right now, it's not entirely clear what he wants, since we haven't seen any markup.